# I can't modify the selected row in JTable with clicking

Tags: java, mouseclick-event

I have a table and the selected row at start is the 0th row. I added a MouseEvent to the table to track the users' click. When the click number is 1, I want to put the focus on the selected row only. When the click number is at least 2, I will do another actions, but it is not part of this questions.

When I run the code, it is not removing the selection from the row, but add it to the current selection.

```
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int row = leftTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                    leftTable.removeRowSelectionInterval(0, leftTable.getRowCount() - 1);
                    leftTable.setRowSelectionInterval(row, 0);
                }
                if (e.getClickCount() >= 2) {
                    System.out.println("selected: " + row);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) will show you how to use a TableModelListener.  The TableModelListener handles row selection and row editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I run the code, it is not removing the selection from the row, but add it to the current selection.

```
leftTable.setRowSelectionInterval(row, 0);
```

Read the API when you use a method.

The API states:

*Selects the rows from index0 to index1, inclusive.*

Since one of your values is always 0, you will always select all rows.

If you only want to select a single row, then both parameters should have the same value.

In any case there is no need for this logic since the table already supports this functionality by default.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems I have problems with understanding the written text. I tried everything exept you mentioned.